# Expression Engine search problem

Tags: expressionengine

We runnig site-s with EE 1.6.8... Not funny, but my boss like it...
So we implemented a search. Everything is fine but the search url is like this:
/search/results/0374c6c40f159934bc6795f031c4e52f10/
instead
/search/results/keyword
The developers said, that only a paid plugin can we put the keyword in the url.
OMG.
Is it true? 
And another Q: after few hours the search url give no results back. It seems, that the session of the cookie expired or anything. 
I have two ideas:
1. Our developers want to fool me
2. EE is so, it's not a cms just a cms like thing...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, the EE Search module uses session-based URLs for results. The reason being that search results are cached for performance, so those results need to expire after a short period of time (as new results might need to appear).

I assume what you want is bookmarkable search results. In this case, I suggest [Super Search](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/super_search/), or on the free, Google-powered end, the [Google Search Results](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-search-results/) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if it would work but in theory you could have www.example.com/search/results/keyword .

In your EE code you would put {exp:weblog:entries search:body="{segment_3}"}title:{title} etc..{/exp:channel:enties} as shown on http://expressionengine.com/legacy_docs/modules/weblog/parameters.html#par_search

The problem is when the keyword contains non [a-z][0-9] characters which is worth considering.

We offer EvoPost on our website for free http://www.eevolution.co.uk/index.php/addons/evopost which will enable you to capture the keywords from a HTTP POST variable e.g. search:body="{ep_txtboxname}"

Feel free to contact us through our website if you need any assistance with the product.

Thanks

Tim

EEvolution Developer